# Does Html.TextBox uses Request.Params instead of Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a simple test application:

Model:

```
public class Counter
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public Counter()
    {
        Count = 4;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Increment(Counter counter)
    {
        counter.Count++;
        return View(counter);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form action="/test/increment" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Count" value="<%= Model.Count %>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Clicking Submit I get such values:

> 5, 6, 7, 8, ...

With Html.TextBox I expected the same behaviour

```
<form action="/test/increment" method="post">
    <%= Html.TextBox("Count") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

but actually got

> 5, 5, 5, 5.

It seems Html.TextBox uses Request.Params instead of Model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Html.TextBox() uses internally ViewData.Eval() method which first attempts to retrieve a value from the dictionary ViewData.ModelState and next to retrieve the value from a property of the ViewData.Model. This is done to allow restoring entered values after invalid form submit.

Removing Count value from ViewData.ModelState dictionary helps:

```
public ActionResult Increment(Counter counter)
{
    counter.Count++;
    ViewData.ModelState.Remove("Count");
    return View(counter);
}
```

Another solution is to make two different controller methods for GET and POST operations:

```
public ActionResult Increment(int? count)
{
    Counter counter = new Counter();

    if (count != null)
        counter.Count = count.Value;

    return View("Increment", counter);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Increment(Counter counter)
{
    counter.Count++;

    return RedirectToAction("Increment", counter);
}
```

Counter object could also be passed via TempData dictionary.

You may also be interested in the article [Repopulate Form Fields with ViewData.Eval()](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-32-repopulate-form-fields-with-viewdata-eval.aspx) by Stephen Walther.

Comment: Then why specifying Model.Count explicitly doesn't work? <%= Html.TextBox("Count", Model.Count) %>

Comment: Because at first Html.TextBox() takes value from ModelState dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the issue here.  Specifying

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Count") %>
```

is equivalent to specifying

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Count", null) %>
```

which will pull the matching value (named "Count") from the ModelStateDictionary.

But even so, explicitly passing in

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Count", Model.Count) %>
```

results in the same behavior described by alex2k8.

Answer (score 0):

Html.TextBox has more parameters than one..first parameter is the name or id of input element, and the second one is the value...

so write your textbox helper like this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Count",Model.Count) %>
```

cheers