# asp.net mvc: is this a bug or a feature when using partial views on objects that have the same field names?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

My classes are a DataModel, which uses ID as its PK, and a Map, which also has ID as a PK.  Map has a FK to DataModel (DataModelID).

I have a partial view that I use from my DataModel list view as follows:

```
 <% foreach (var map in Model.Map)
    { %>
 <% Html.RenderPartial("MapEdit", map); %>
 <% } %>
```

My MapEdit partial view looks like:

```
Before: <%= Html.Encode(Model.ID) %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
    <label for="ID">ID:</label>
    <%= Html.TextBox("ID", Model.ID) %>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("ID", "*") %>
<% } %>
```

When I run this, I would expect to see ([ ] represent a textbox):

```
Before: 4
ID: [ 4 ]

Before: 5
ID: [ 5 ]

etc...
```

Where each number is the actual ID from the record. What I actually get is:

```
Before: 4
ID: [ 10 ]

Before: 5
ID: [ 10 ]
```

10 in this case happens to be the ID from the DataModel!  I have no idea where this is coming from, because stepping thru the code shows that Model.ID has the correct value - at some point however it's getting replaced.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Model.Map` is null, `Model` will be passed to the partial view instead. That's how partial views work.

Also, model values are copied to the `ModelStateDictionary`, which can have only one key called `ID`. This makes sense since any form you submit would use the keys as the form field name.

`ModelStateDictionary` values supercede model values so that the form can be re-rendered with invalid user input when necessary. Usually, model and model state values are the same on initial (non-error) display. But this isn't the same if you have duplicate keys.

Comment: And the solution is using prefixes and list binding (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).

Comment: +1, concise.  There's more explanation on this thread as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953330/does-html-textbox-uses-request-params-instead-of-model

Comment: Model is not null.  The 3 and 4 are the right IDs, and stepping thru the code the Model.ID is getting passed to the html.TextBox with the correct value - but at some point it gets replaced.

Comment: LukLed, that post was accurate at the time, but list binding has changed since it was written. The index is (1) no longer a separate field (2) required to be an integer (3) must start at zero and (4) must be sequential.

Comment: @chris: Don't use the same names ("ID") in view and partial views. it doesn't work well with ModelState. Use prefixes: Html.TextBox("maps[index].ID", Model.ID).

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: I know, but it gives good overview and I knew that someone will add comment about index:)

Comment: @LukLed: That worked.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @chris: Craig Stuntz actually answered your question. It is good to know how ModelState works, it will save you some time:)