# MVC5 TextBoxFor() not rending bound value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

Do not know why MVC5 has stopped binding textbox, the value is only being shown if it was part of the request, not if I set it manually.

This prints the correct property value:

```
  @Html.Raw(Model.MyStringField)
```

This prints a input box that does not have a value, i.e. `value=""`

```
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyStringField, new
                                {
                                    @class = "myCssClass",
                                    placeholder = "Test",
                                    autocomplete = "off"
                                })
```

What could be going wrong?

MVC Hates me, these code items are on the same line but return different values:

```
Model.Location = "TEST";
@Html.Raw(Model.Location) // Prints TEST
@Html.TextBox(@"Location", Model.Location) // Prints value from postback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns our after reading [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297670/what-am-i-misunderstanding-about-how-html-textboxfor-works) about values not being read after postback is that hte HTML Helpers, whilst told to use model values, actually use the ModelState value. So calling `ModelState.Clear();` is needed to reset it and force it to use the model.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another @ symbol before "class" and "Location". I think you're trying to start razor syntax, when it's already started and confusing things.

try these edits:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyStringField, new
                            {
                                class = "myCssClass",
                                placeholder = "Test",
                                autocomplete = "off"
                            })
    @Html.TextBox("Location", Model.Location) // Prints value from postback
```

Comment: Thanks; but the @ is actually necessary since 'class' is a reserved keyword and the @ escapes it (won't compile without the @), @"Location" makes a literal string, so stops Visual Studio highlighting it as a 'localisable' string, since in this case it's a variable name and wouldn't change between language since it'll mess up form variable.